# Paragraph ended before \tikz@intersect@path@names@parse was complete

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds,matrix,patterns}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
\footnotesize   

\draw[<->] (0,3.6) node[above]{$y$}--(0,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};

\draw[red, name path=D, dashed] (0,0)--(3.5,3.5);

\foreach \i in {1,2,3}{
    \draw[name path global = I\i] (0,0) plot [domain=0.4+(\i-1)*0.38:4.7] (\x,\i*1.4/\x) node[right]{I$_\i$};
    \path [name intersections={of=I\i and D,by=P\i}];
    \draw[fill,red] (P1\i) circle[radius=1.3pt] node[above,red, shift={(0,0.1)}]{\i};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I get the error:

> Paragraph ended before \tikz@intersect@path@names@parse was complete.

Why is this happening? I've used similar loops before with no issue. In fact, if you take out the last two lines in the loop and just do:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
\footnotesize   

\draw[<->] (0,3.6) node[above]{$y$}--(0,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};

\draw[red, name path=D, dashed] (0,0)--(3.5,3.5);

\foreach \i in {1,2,3}{
    \draw[name path global = I\i] (0,0) plot [domain=0.4+(\i-1)*0.38:4.7] (\x,\i*1.4/\x) node[right]{I$_\i$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It compiles with no issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reversing `I\i` and `D` solves your problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
\footnotesize   
\draw[<->] (0,3.6) node[above]{$y$}--(0,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[red, name path=D, dashed] (0,0)--(3.5,3.5);
\foreach \i in {1,2,3}{
    \draw[name path global = I\i] (0,0) plot [domain=0.4+(\i-1)*0.38:4.7] (\x,\i*1.4/\x) node[right]{I$_\i$};
    \path [name intersections={of=D and I\i,by=P\i}];
    \draw[fill,red] (P\i) circle[radius=1.3pt] node[above,red, shift={(0,0.1)}]{\i};% <- What is P1\i???
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tikz]

Or, you should surround your `I\i` within a pair of `{}`:

```
\path[name intersections={of={I\i} and D,by=P\i}];
```

But I would use a re-parametrization of the functions `f(x) = \i*1.4/x`. Notice how the sloppy left yields bad-looking straight segments in the above graph. So, why not use `<input> = sqrt(\i*1.4) * exp(x)` and `<output> = sqrt(\i*1.4) * exp(-x)`, so their product is the constant `\i*1.4`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
\footnotesize   
\draw[<->]
  (0,3.6) node[above] {$y$} --
  (0,0) --
  (5,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[red,name path=D,dashed]
  (0,0) -- (3.5,3.5);
\foreach \i in {1,2,3} {
  \draw[name path global=I\i]
    (0,0) plot[domain={ln(2*sqrt(\i/35))}:{ln(47/2/sqrt(35*\i))}]
            ({sqrt(\i*1.4)*exp(\x)},{sqrt(\i*1.4)*exp(-\x)}) node[right] {$I_\i$};
  \path[name intersections={of=D and I\i,by=P\i}];
  \draw[fill,red]
    (P\i) circle[radius=1.3pt]
          node[above,red,shift={(0,0.1)}] {\i};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tikz2]

Comment: That was pretty stunning. Thank you for the additional comments - will use it, and replicate the method in future!