# Problem With Plotting Square Root in TIKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Does anyone know why this plot looks funny between 0 and 1 ? The same will happen if I try to plot the cube root function. Please advise. I am trying to avoid using pgfplots package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6,cap=round]
\tikzset{axes/.style={}}
  % The graphic
\draw[style=help lines,step=1cm, dotted] (-.5,-3.5) grid (10.5,5.5);
\begin{scope}[style=axes]
\draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (10.5,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-3.5) -- (0,5.5) node[above] {$y$};
    \foreach \x/\xtext in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
\draw[xshift=\x cm] (0pt,2.6pt) -- (0pt,-2.6pt) node[below,fill=white]
         {\scriptsize $\xtext$};
\foreach \y/\ytext in {-3, -2, -1,  1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
\draw[yshift=\y cm] (2.6pt,0pt) -- (-2.6pt,0pt) node[left,fill=white]
        {\scriptsize $\ytext$};
%\filldraw[blue] (0,0) circle (3pt) node[fill=white,below right=12pt] 
{\scriptsize $(0,0)$};
\filldraw[blue] (1,1) circle (3pt) node[fill=white,above=3pt] {\scriptsize 
$(1,1)$};
\filldraw[blue] (3,1.732) circle (3pt) node[fill=white,below=3pt] 
 {\scriptsize $(3,\sqrt{3})$};
\filldraw[blue] (4,2) circle (3pt) node[fill=white,above=3pt] {\scriptsize 
$(4,2)$};
\filldraw[blue] (9,3) circle (3pt) node[fill=white,above=3pt] {\scriptsize 
$(9,3)$};
\draw[domain=0:10,smooth,variable=\x,blue,thick,->] plot ({\x},{(\x)^.5});
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ti*k*Z loads the `pgf` package as it builds upon that.

Comment: I suppose I mean without using pgfplots. What is the advantage? Also I will try to rewrite this function in terms of logarithms to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: A much, much simpler solution without increasing sampling points is `\draw[domain=0:3.162278,smooth,variable=\x,blue,thick,->] plot (\x^2,\x);` I always find [re-parameterizing the function produces better looking results](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449058/164314).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your sample is not large enough: by default it is 25 points.  With a sample of 200 points, this works.

**Edit:** Modification of the sample. Many thanks to Skillmon for having the idea to modify the sample and to @marmot for giving a simple and effective example.

Your `\foreach` loops do not need to have two variables. Only one is enough, for the displayed text to be smaller, there is the key `font=\scriptsize`.

**Edit 2:**
And to avoid repeating this for each node, just do it with `every node/.style={font=\scriptsize}` to overwrite the pre-existing style or `every node/append style={font=\scriptsize}` to simply add this style to the pre-existing style without overwriting it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6,cap=round,every node/.style={font=\scriptsize}]
\tikzset{axes/.style={}}
  % The graphic
\draw[style=help lines,step=1cm, dotted] (-.5,-3.5) grid (10.5,5.5);
\begin{scope}[style=axes]
\draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (10.5,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-3.5) -- (0,5.5) node[above] {$y$};
    \foreach \x in {1, ..., 10}
\draw[xshift=\x cm] (0pt,2.6pt) -- (0pt,-2.6pt) node[below,fill=white]
         { \x};
\foreach \y in {-3,..., 5}
\draw[yshift=\y cm] (2.6pt,0pt) -- (-2.6pt,0pt) node[left,fill=white]
        { \y};

\filldraw[blue] (0,0) circle (3pt) node[fill=white,below right=12pt] 
{$(0,0)$};
\filldraw[blue] (1,1) circle (3pt) node[fill=white,above=3pt] {
$(1,1)$};
\filldraw[blue] (3,1.732) circle (3pt) node[fill=white,below=3pt] 
 {$(3,\sqrt{3})$};
\filldraw[blue] (4,2) circle (3pt) node[fill=white,above=3pt] {
$(4,2)$};
\filldraw[blue] (9,3) circle (3pt) node[fill=white,above=3pt] {
$(9,3)$};
\draw[domain=0:10,smooth,variable=\x,blue,thick,->,samples at={0,0.05,...,1,1.5,...,10.5}] plot ({\x},{(\x)^.5});
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I'd suggest raising the number of samples only in the interval [0,1] and not on the rest. This way one could use less samples (better performance). The gradient isn't changing much on the interval [1,10], so one doesn't need that many.

Comment: @Skillmon It's a good idea, but since I'm starting with pgfplots, I don't know how to do it. Write an answer explaining how to do it!

Comment: @Andre' , Thanks and In your opinion is there advantage using pgfplots instead? For some reason I want to do all my plotting as in the example above. Again Thanks!

Comment: Just split the plot in two parts, like `\draw[domain=0:1, samples=50, smooth, variable=\x] plot ({\x},{(\x)^.5}); \draw[domain=1:10, smooth, variable=\x] plot ({\x},{(\x)^.5});`. By the way, you're not using `pgfplots` here, but Ti*k*Z and its plot capabilities (`pgfplots` is another package) :)

Comment: @MathScholar I've never used `pgfplots` myself (only when I stumbled upon a question about it) and am no frequent user of Ti*k*Z. So I don't feel like the right person to ask this, sorry.

Comment: @Skillmon `samples at={0,0.05,...,1,1.5,...,10}`.

Comment: @MathScholar I don't know if there is an advantage to using pgfplots, tkz-fct, tikz, gnuplot or others. In my opinion, when you start out, it is easier to focus on learning a single package. If it is no longer enough to do what you want to do, then it becomes imperative to learn another one. Not before. From this point of view, it is preferable to learn tikz as a priority.

Comment: `every nodes` is grammatically incorrect and doesn't do anything. Try `every node/.append style={font=\scriptsize}`.

Comment: @marmot Thank you very much for your attention. I put node in plural while it is singular and it now works correctly with `every node/.style={font=\scriptsize}` I updated the answer.

Comment: `append style` might be a better choice, though, since this avoids overwriting pre-existing node styles...

Comment: @marmot I take your word for it because I don't fully understand the explanations in the manual on this subject. Can you explain this more simply than the manual?

Comment: I think it is very simple. Consider `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{every node/.style={red}}
\node at (0,0) {C};
\tikzset{every node/.append style={draw}}
\node at (1,0) {C};
\tikzset{every node/.style={draw}}
\node at (2,0) {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`. The second node is red and has a frame while the last one only has a frame. That is, with `append style` you add something to pre-existing styles, and with `style` you just overwrite it.

Comment: @marmot You explain it wonderfully well, thank you. I feel like I'm getting smart, thank you so much!

Comment: @marmot thank you, didn't know `samples at`!

Answer (score 1):

a small variation of nice  @AndréC answer (+1): one more loop, calculation of marks positions, ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6,
every node/.append style = {font=\scriptsize, inner sep=2pt, xscale=0.9}
                        ]
% grid
\draw[help lines,dotted] (0,-3.5) grid (10.5,5.5);
% axis
\draw[->] (-0.4,0) -- (10.5,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-3.5) -- ( 0,5.5) node[above] {$y$};
\foreach \x in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    \draw (\x,2pt) -- + (0,-4pt) node[below,fill=white] {\x};
\foreach \y in {-3,...,5}
    \draw (2pt,\y) -- + (-4pt,0) node[left, fill=white] {\y};
% curve
\draw[smooth, blue,thick,->]
    plot[samples at={0,0.05,...,1,1.5,...,10.5}] (\x,\x^.5);
% marks
\foreach \i/\j in {0/0, 1/1, 3/$\sqrt{3}$, 4/2, 9/3}
{   \pgfmathparse{sqrt(\i)}
    \fill[blue]  (\i,\pgfmathresult)
        circle[radius=2pt] \ifnum\i>0 node[above=1pt] {(\i,\j)}\fi;
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]